# Grails not creating a new log file after size limit is exceeded

Tags: grails, log4j

Here is the sample from my `Config.groovy`

```
appenders {
            rollingFile  name:'myLogFile', 
            file:'./myLogFile.log', 
            threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.ALL, 
            maxFileSize:'10KB'
        }
        root {
            error 'myLogFile'
            additivity = true
        }
```

I have set the `maxFileSize to 10KB` to quickly check whether `log4j` will create a new file after exceeding the `size limit`. But it does not seem to be working. Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        rollingFile name:'logfile',
        maxFileSize:1024000,
        maxBackupIndex:10,
        file:"/Users/me/someappname.log",
        layout:pattern(conversionPattern:'%d %c %m%n')
    }

    root {
        warn 'logfile'
        additivity = true
    }
    blah blah blah
}
```

works for me.